# Modify text in the PDF invoice

Tags: pdf

Where I can change the text in the PDF invoice?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the code or copy code from **app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php** to **app\code\local\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php** line 78.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but with this change we only managed to modify the text in the product and not in the Total. --->         http://www.ecopasion.com/prueba222.png

Answer (score 1):

Copy the code from

`app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Abstract.php` to

`app\code\local\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Abstract.php line no 590`. you can edit labels.

Rewrite the code or copy code from

`app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php` to

`app\code\local\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php line 78.`

Answer (score 1):

You can change the text by adding a translate.csv file to the admin theme and translate the line. app/design/adminhtml/default/default/locale/en_US/translate.csv